# Redis DB is not connecting in server - c#

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am using the below source to connect the Redis db with TLS certificate. the below code works fine on my local machine and my colleague's machines. but when I deploy the code to my Dev/QA servers, it fails to connect to the database.

I got the logs from the server and compared with my local machine logs..
the local machine logs are generated as below
[image]
QA server log:

[image]

I can see that the SSL configuration is success on my local machine but not on the server.

can I get help on this? I'm unable to find what is the issue and how to fix it.

```
logging.Info("Redis Connection started");
        var appPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/");
        var reportsPath = Path.Combine(appPath, "Reports");
        RedisSettings redisSettings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RedisSettings>(CoreConfigurationManager.RedisConfiguration);

        var configurationOptions = new ConfigurationOptions
        {
            EndPoints = { redisSettings.EndPoints },
            Ssl = true,
            SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Default,
            Password = redisSettings.Password,
            AbortOnConnectFail = false
        };
        logging.Info($"Redis EndPoint : {redisSettings.EndPoints}");
        dynamic storage = new FileStorage();
        try
        {
            configurationOptions.CertificateSelection += delegate (object sender, string host,
            X509CertificateCollection certificates, X509Certificate certificate, string[] issuers)
            {
                var cert = new X509Certificate2(redisSettings.CertFilePath, redisSettings.CertFilePassword);
                return cert;
            };
            logging.Info($"Redis pfx file path : {redisSettings.CertFilePath}");

            configurationOptions.CertificateValidation += delegate (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain,
                SslPolicyErrors errors)
            {
                //validation logic
                return true;
            };

            var redisEnabled = redisSettings.IsEnabled;
            logging.Info($"Redis configuration enabled status : {redisEnabled}");




            if (redisEnabled)
            {
                var log = new StringWriter();
                var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configurationOptions, log);
                if (redis.IsConnected)
                {
                    storage = new RedisStorage(redis, reportsPath);
                    logging.Debug($"Redis DB Connected success");
                }
                var logOutput = log.ToString();
                logging.Debug($"Redis DB Connection log : {logOutput}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            NewRelic.Api.Agent.NewRelic.NoticeError(ex);
            logging.Error("Exception on Redis DB connection: " + ex.Message, ex);
        }
```

Comment: Read GREEN note at following : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/cheatsheets/how-to-connect-to-a-redis-database#connecting-to-redis-remotely